# Why is a large quantum annealer likely to leave its ground state?

Tags: optimization, annealing

For problems of significant size in quantum annealing, I have read that even for slow transitions, the annealer is likely to leave its ground state. I have not fully grasped the meaning of why exactly the likelihood of leaving the ground state increases with problem size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adiabatic theorem states that in order to remain close to the ground state throughout an annealing path, the annealing time must scale polynomially with the inverse of the spectral gap of the Hamiltonian (at any point in time along the path). Spectral gaps typically scale inversely with system size, for example solvable 1D spin chains (such as the transverse-field Ising model or antiferromagnetic Heisenberg model) have a spectral gap that scales as $\Delta \sim L^{-1}$ for $L$ spins. Thus as the system grows larger, the spectral gap closes and so the annealing time will need to increase as well in order to remain adiabatic.

I suppose it depends on what they mean by "slow transitions" in the material you have read - if the minimum spectral gap along the path is only polynomial in $L^{-1}$, then the required annealing time will only scale polynomially with $L$, which is formally efficient from a computational perspective. On the other hand we know that many hard problems have exponentially closing gaps, which translates to a total time that scales exponentially in $L$. Indeed we expect this to be the case, otherwise quantum annealing would be able to solve NP-hard problems in polynomial time, which we don't expect to be possible!